# I tried to backup my harddrive, and now I cannot boot nor access my hard drive

Tags: boot, hard-drive, backup, fsck

When I am trying to boot, it says

```
/dev/nvme01n1p5: clean, 797810/24895488 files, 99262092/99558656 blocks
```

What happened before:

- Following a post on this website I used `dd` to clone my drive to an external usb stick.
- This also failed eventually (while I was cloning from `nvme0n1p5`), with the message that there was no more hard disk space.
- When I checked how much disk space I would need for the backup I was quite floored: the disk `nvme0n1p5` was full: 423/423 GB used. What I now see: my USB stick still has 900GB free.
- I restarted. Since then I see the error from above
- I tried to "free" space by deleting unused packages, which came up to a couple of hundred megabyes
- I booted from a USB and did fsck, which showed that everything was cleared.
- Booting from `nvme01n1p1`, the windows partition, works fine.

What now?

Comment: What is the exact command you used? An improper `dd` can have rather devastating consequences ...

Comment: @matigo there is no way of recovering that. I `thought` that I was doing `dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p5 of=./part5.image`, while being in /media/myuser/backup, and I `thought` that "backup" was mounted to the external USB drive. I did see a couple of files in that USB drive, so thats why I thought that I was making progress. But clearly, something went wrong somewhere.